# Binding ArrayList to jqgrid

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc, arraylist, jqgrid

Is it possible to dynamically bind an ArrayList to a jqgrid?My list will contain the object equivalent to the row of the grid and my idea is as and when I add or remove an element from the list it should get immediately be reflected in the grid
I am using Spring MVC 3 framework.

Comment: I think that's possible. I use a similar framework (http://www.jqwidgets.com). There i working with lists, maps etc. Have you any code?

Comment: @Harish,  Can you add jqgrid code